# Discord.JS RichEmbed Building

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

fellow Developers!  I've been having a ton of issue over the past couple hours with Discord.JS's embedding technique.  I keep getting:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined
>       at new MessageEmbed (folder\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessageEmbed.js:13:60)
>       at embed (folder\rlxob.js:17:13)
>       at Client.client.on.message(folder\rlxob.js:193:15)

And from what I understand, the rest beyond that doesn't matter, but [here's a Gyazo image](https://gyazo.com/eb092c0975e8b32ba4c81631d3724586) if you want to see the entire output.  MessageEmbed.js line 13 says `Object.defineProperty(this, 'client', { value: message.client });` which is leaving me a bit confused.  It seems to expect the `message` variable to already be defined in `class MessageEmbed {constructor (message, data) {` but my code matches up with every single tutorial on message embedding that I have checked, double-checked, and gonna find out who's naughty or nice.  And this piece of... well, I have no nice words to say, so I won't say any of them.  To leave you with a few bits of information that might help, `node` is running on version `8.9.4` and `Discord.JS` is running on version `11.2.1`.  This is really getting on my nerves, there isn't a clear answer that I can figure out.  Thanks for the help, guys!  If you need any new information, I'll be checking back here.  If I don't reply, probably means I figured it out, however unlikely that may be.

Comment: Can you show the code you're using with MessageEmbed, not just the error?

Answer (score 1):

I understand you have double checked but just to make sure this is my embed that works fine:

```
case "info":
  var embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .addField("General-Commands", "::games, ::people")
    .addField("Other-Commands", "::example, ::gamble")
    .addField(
      "Music-Commands",
      "::play <playlisturl>/search, ::skip, ::pause/resume, ::stop, ::queue"
    );
  message.channel.sendEmbed(embed);
  break;
```

Comment: If this doesn't work it's likely going to be something to do with corrupted node files or something else on your side

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't define `Client`, so this is what you'll have to add:

```
const client = new Discord.Client({disableEveryone: true})
```

Note: `{disableEveryone}` is optional.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! :) Kindly use proper formatting for lines of code that appear in your answer. For in-line code, you can use back-tick character (`) and for snippets of code, use four spaces before each line (or simply select the code block and click the code option from formatting tools.